# Cordova (phonegap) as service

Tags: cordova

i've tried a few plugins to set the phonegap apk as a service so that it creates a notification on the statusbar when some events happens... but none of them seems to be updated and both crashes with the actual phonegap (2.9.0)

The plugis i tried are : [this](https://github.com/Red-Folder/Cordova-Plugin-BackgroundService/tree/master/2.7.0) (for running it as a service) and [this](https://github.com/manijshrestha/PhonegapStatusNotificationDemo) for the statusbar notification

Does anyone know how to handle this two services?

Thanks.